# Link to node in views

Tags: 7, views, nodes, navigation

I have a view which has 2 displays :

- List : Which is a unformatted list that contains a page
- Table : Displays the nodes titles in a table.

What i need is to make the title in each row of the second display redirect to the corresponding node in the first display, regardless of the "item per page" and sorting.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of list you have in the first display? Basically -if I understand correctly– you will need to set a contextual filter (probably the Node ID) to display the correct node...

Comment: I know about contextual filters, but I want to display all the nodes in the list but position the user on the selected node

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be a good way to start with
1.I think you will need views_infinite_scroll module for the list view.
2. Set your views listing path as path/%
3. For list view set row classes as nids
3. Now with custom jquery code you take the nid from url and do a $.scrollTo(..) and nids set as row classes may help you finding the appropriate position to scroll to.
does it make sense?

Comment: if my list was on one page then I can easily make the link in the table `/articles/list#node-[nid]` and that would work, but the I'm using a pager for the list